# redux reducer return 'defaultState' is it safe to do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

Question is it safe to return defaultState in reducer. if not safe please give me an example, when there is chance the state get mutated.

```
const defaultState = {
    test: 'test
}

function testReducer(state, action) {
    switch action.type
        case RETURN_DEFAULT_STATE:
        return defaultState; // is this ok to do? or need {...defaultState}
    default:
        return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not mutating `defaultState` somewhere else and it reflects the new state you want, I don't see what the problem would be.

Here are some examples of how `defaultState` could conceivably be mutated:

With no modification to your example code:

```js
store.dispatch({type: "RETURN_DEFAULT_STATE"});
store.getState().x = "x";
```

Note that you shouldn't be doing this anyway and already have a problem if you are.

Now, a modified version of your example code:

```js
export const defaultState = {
    test: 'test
}

function testReducer(state, action) {
    switch action.type
        case RETURN_DEFAULT_STATE:
        return defaultState; // is this ok to do? or need {...defaultState}
    default:
        return someOtherReducer(state, action);
}

function someOtherReducer(state, action) {
  state.x = "x";
  return state;
}
```

Note that you shouldn't be doing what `someOtherReducer()` is anyway and already have a problem if you are.

```js
import {defaultState} from "whatever";

defaultState.x = "x";
```

```js
store.dispatch({type: "RETURN_DEFAULT_STATE"});
store.dispatch({type: "UNKNOWN"});
```

Comment: how could i mutate defaultState somewhere else? can you provide an example?

Comment: By mutating state in a subsequent reducer, by retrieving the state with `store.getState()` and mutating it, but passing / exporting `defaultState` somewhere (this isn't evident in the example code you posted) and mutating it.

Comment: would be nice to see a bad example how defaultState can be mutated by passing / exporting. at the moment i dont see it happening but like you said it's possible

Comment: Updated with some examples.

Comment: best to stick with {...defaultState}

Answer (score 1):

It is safe so long as all the developers writing the code adhere to not mutating input parameters. I would still suggest to do `Object.assign` to prevent any accidental mutations.

Faulty code sample:

```
const defaultState = {
    test: 'test'
};

function testReducer(state, action) {
    switch action.type
        case RETURN_DEFAULT_STATE:
        return defaultState; // is this ok to do? or need {...defaultState}
        case DO_MALICIOS_MUTATION:
        state.test='foo'; // this might potentially mutate original defaultState object
        return defaultState;
    default:
        return state;
}
```

Comment: nice example... yeah probably stick with {...defaultState}

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't mutate it anywhere. However, I happen to have experienced a bug caused by an object being mutated by accident. Therefore I recommend if you want to be sure your state is not mutated you can freeze the default state object:

```
const defaultState = Object.freeze({
    test: 'test
});
```

If you try to modify such a frozen object in a strict mode you get an exception.

Comment: nice nice object. freeze